# I am getting Fragment cast error even while I am creating new GoogleMapsActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am getting error "Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapfragment".
I have use `FragmentActivity` to show map.

This is my code please help me for this.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Error

```
error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment
```

I have followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: show `R.layout.activity_maps` layout XML

Comment: I edited my code for layout file kindy look into this. thanks

Comment: You need to use `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` instead of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`. Or even `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: didn't worked for me .

Comment: why? what it says now? Also show your actual code

Comment: can you post your logcat error?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran I cant able to build because I have an error in java code. for which I asking help.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko please look into question I already edited my question for xml code and error.

Comment: I still see you using `android:name`. Either it is not actual code, or you did not try my suggestion

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried with both class and android:name but this is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

[SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) for ref. Use class instead of name

Answer (score 0):

Go to your layout activity_maps.xml and replace this line:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

with this:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

It should look like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

You have to use SupportMapFragment which extends Fragment from support library.

Comment: Yes I already included this line. but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Mr.Moudgil Did you REPLACE the line with the one I provided?

Comment: I already used that line of code. This is already included when we create a new Google map activity.